Coin toss stochastic question
Question:
There are $n$ people playing a game. Initially everybody had one dollar at hand. During each round of the game, we randomly pick two people and they will toss a fair coin, to decide who wins this round of the game. The loser will submit one dollar (note: just one, not all of his money) to the winner. Assume that a person who had no money at hand will be immediately driven out of the game. The game continues until all money is at the hand of only one person. Calculate the average number of rounds that the game plays.
Note:

In each round only two players are involved.
If someone reaches 0 dollar, he will be immediately eliminated.
Randomly pick means the choice of the 2 people every round is uniformly distributed on the space of 2-combinations of the active players, and that all random events are independent of each other.

Initial thoughts:
If $2$ players play this game. One has $n$ dollars, the other has $m-n$ dollars. Then we have $0$ and $m$ being absorbing states, and for all other $n$, we have the transitions $n\to n+1$ and $n\to n-1$ both with $50\%$ probability. We use $E_i$ to represent the expected rounds that the game plays when one player have $i$ dollar in hand.
So we can write down the state-transition equations:
\begin{align*}
E_0 & = 0 = E_m \\
E_n & = 1 + \frac12(E_{n-1} + E_{n+1}).
\end{align*}
Then we can use the characteristic function to find the solution: $E_n=n(m-n)$.
My friend says we can construct a martingale from Markov processes of this $2$ player question, then use Doob stopping time theorem to solve it. But I don't know how to construct such martingale. And we both have no idea with the $n$ people question.

This paper seems to be relevant to your question: https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642669

Name of the paper referenced by @SergueiPopov: Ross - A Simple Solution to a Multiple Player Gambler's Ruin Problem.

This has been beautifully solved as shown by Serguei Popov's comment.
I was going to suggest looking at the probabilities to go from an integer partition of $n$ to another. For $n=4$ they are
$$1111\overset{1}\longrightarrow 211\overset{1/3}\longrightarrow 211\overset{1/3}\longrightarrow 31\overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 22\overset{1}\longrightarrow 31\overset{1/2}\longrightarrow 4\quad\text{ and }\quad211\overset{1/3}\longrightarrow 22\;.$$
This translates into equations between the expected number of rounds for each partition :
$$\begin{array}{r,l,r}\mathrm{E}_{1111} =1&+&\mathrm{E}_{211}&&\\
\mathrm{E}_{211} =1&+&\frac{1}{3}\mathrm{E}_{211}&+&\frac{1}{3}\mathrm{E}_{22}&+&\frac{1}{3}\mathrm{E}_{31}\\
\mathrm{E}_{22}=1&+&&&&&\mathrm{E}_{31}\\
\mathrm{E}_{31}=1&+&&&\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{E}_{22}&+&\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{E}_{4}\\
\mathrm{E}_{4}=0
\end{array}$$
or equivalently
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0&0\\0&\frac{2}{3}&-\frac{1}{3}&-\frac{1}{3}&0\\0&0&1&-1&0\\0&0&-\frac{1}{2}&1&-\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{E}_{1111}\\\mathrm{E}_{211}\\\mathrm{E}_{22}\\\mathrm{E}_{31}\\\mathrm{E}_{4}\end{pmatrix} =  
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Inverting the matrix yields
$$\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{E}_{1111}\\\mathrm{E}_{211}\\\mathrm{E}_{22}\\\mathrm{E}_{31}\\\mathrm{E}_{4}\end{pmatrix} =  
\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{3}{2}&\frac{3}{2}&2&1\\0&\frac{3}{2}&\frac{3}{2}&2&1\\0&0&2&2&1\\0&0&1&2&1\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}6\\5\\4\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
therefore the answer is $6$ when $n=4$.
You can ask a computer algebra system to do it for other small values. In PARI/GP
newstateindex(S,x,p,q) = {
  x[p]++; x[q]--;
  x = vecsort(x);
  if(!x[1], x = x[2..-1]);
  setsearch(S,x)
}

transitionmatrix(n) = {
  my(S = partitions(n), M = matid(#S));
  for(stateindex = 1, #S,
    my(x = S[stateindex]);
    for(p = 1, #x-1, \\ player 1
      for(q = p+1, #x, \\ player 2
        M[stateindex, newstateindex(S,x,p,q)] -= 1/#x/(#x-1);
        M[stateindex, newstateindex(S,x,q,p)] -= 1/#x/(#x-1)
      )
    )
  );
  M
}

default(parisizemax, 10^10)
for(n=1, 21, M = transitionmatrix(n); E = matsolve(M,vector(#M,i,i>1)~); print(n,"  ",E[#E],"  ",E))

It quickly outputs $n(n-1)/2$ as an answer for $n=1,2,\dots,25$. Unfortunately this isn't enough to hint at the beautiful resolution by Sheldon M Ross.
